# Firefox position issue for footer area?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, firefox

This is the website: 
http://www.themebia.com/pretavivre/

If you view it in Chrome, the footer area for copyright section is render perfectly.

But If you view it in Firefox, the footer area for copyright section shows blank? Why is this happening in Firefox?

In IE it shows internal scroll bar  and white unwanted space at bottom of page?

I've used parent container as position to relative and then footer copyright section as position to absolute.

Second, some of my tags in Firefox are shown like inactive: http://screencast.com/t/JCunmblC

Can someone help me with copyright section in FF? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have invalid markup, so Firefox is making a different best guess to Chrome.  Specifically, in `<div id="home-footer-social-icons">` you have `<a/>` instead of `</a>`.  There are a few other issues (see [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.themebia.com/pretavivre/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)), but that one seems a good place to start.

Comment: I've corrected the </a> but still same issue on FireFox. Thanks